# Should I see the backlinks from my old redirected domain in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect, backlinks

I've `301` permanently redirected my old domain. Should I see the backlinks from my old domain in my new domain's Search Console property, or do they not show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see them. I think the report will indicate that they come via your old domain. It may also require that you have the old domain verified.